# How to hide element if second element receive an specific class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hide, show-hide

For example we have 2 button

First button
`<button class="arguments variation-one">Some text</button>` - this button have dynamic classes like: variation-one, variation-two, variation-three, but class .arguments is static.

and Second button
`<button class="simple">Other text</button>`

I must hide second button if first button receiving class .variation-two, without on click events. By js, jQuery, or even css if its possible. Please help me.

Im find similar problem on this forum and solution was this script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $redTags = $('.lt-label');
    if($redTags.hasClass(".lt-offline") {
        $("#l-b-wrapper").hide();
    }
}
```

I tried to interpret it to suit my task, but nothing worked for me

Comment: Rather than describing your HTML, could you post your (relevant, representative) HTML in the question, as you've already done (thanks!) for your jQuery? Incidentally, the class-names you mention are very much absent from your posted jQuery, which is likely to attract comments as to why it's not working).

Comment: We need more info because the classes and id in your JS have no obvious relationship to the button HTML you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if there's any buttons that has `arguments` and `variation-two` classes. If there's, hide the second button with `simple` class.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    let element = $(".arguments.variation-two");
    if(element.length > 0) {
        $(".simple").hide();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="arguments variation-two">Some Text</button> 
<button class="simple">Other Text</button>
```

Comment: Thank for your help. Your code is greate and its work! But i find very simple solution by css, id and :has

Answer (score 0):

This will hide the second button if the first button has the `variation-one` class.

```
$(function() {
  $(".simple").toggle(!$(".arguments").hasClass("variation-one"))
});
```

Note that this runs when the page is first loaded. If you want to hide and show the second button dynamically when the first button's class changes, you need to run the code every time it changes. Either put this in a named function that you call from all the places that change the first button's class, or use [`MutationObserver`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-javascript-jquery-dom-change-listener) to detect changes automatically.